# Program not executing thread

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have two files, the first is a swing class and the second is my thread class. When I run my thread for for some reason it doesn't run, I tried by placing some print statements to see if my program would ever get there but none of them ran.

My thread class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class CheckFiles implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        while (!UserInterface.stop) {
            try {

                String line;

                BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(UserInterface.location));

                while((line = b.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(line);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }
    }
}
```

In my **UserInterface** class I start the method by doing the following

```
System.out.println(stop); //prints true
loadFile.setEnabled(false); //not important
status.setText("Checking Files"); //not important
stop = false; 
System.out.println(stop); //prints false
new CheckFiles(); //start thread
```

Is there something that is stopping my thread from running or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: A little hint: Make sure that `UserInterface.stop` is volataile, becouse you are using a variable in two different threads without synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a class that can be used to start a thread, but you are not starting it.

Several solutions are possible:

**Solution 1:**

Change the type to extend `Thread`

```
class CheckFiles extends Thread {
    ...
}
```

and change the last line to

```
(new CheckFiles()).start();
```

**Solution 2:**

Keep `CheckFiles` a `Runnable`, and change the last line to

```
(new Thread(new CheckFiles())).start();
```

Comment: What's the difference between making it runnable and extending a thread?

Comment: @user2612619 `Runnable` is an interface, you can use it if your thread class must extend some other class. If there is no requirement to extend another class, you can extend `Thread` to simplify the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you only made your class Runnable. You need to create and start your thread. Please take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new CheckFiles());
t.start();
```

The main differences between extending Thread, and implementing your target Runnable is that when extending Thread you are associating the Thread with the object you are creating. By making your Object runnable, you are able to associate your Thread with many runnable objects..

Answer (score 1):

You should'nt make the class extend thread, rather do something like

```
Thread t = new Thread(new CheckFiles());
t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have created an instance of the class that is supposed to be a `Thread`! You have to actually declare a `Thread` and start it. e.g. `new Thread(new CheckFiles()).start();` to create an instance of the thread, the object and start it.