# Program not stopping thread

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have a thread, which I previously could not get running but that's now been solved thanks to a member on this site, that question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883942/program-not-executing-thread).

To stop my thread I created a boolean in the thread class and set it to **false**, if it is set to **true** then the thread should stop. I even check when I am stopping the thread by printing the thread but it prints **true** (which it should) but the thread keeps on running.

My thread (**CheckFiles.java**) class looks like this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class CheckFiles extends Thread {

    static boolean stop = false;

    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + stop);
            try {

                String line;

                BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(UserInterface.location));

                while((line = b.readLine()) != null) {

                    Ststem.out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }

        }
    }

}
```

To stop the thread I have a button and the code of it looks like this.

```
 stopChecking.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            CheckFiles.stop = true;
            System.out.println(CheckFiles.stop); //Prints true when pressed

        }
    });
```

Why is my thread not stopping, or is there a better way to do it?

EDIT: When I try interrupting the thread I get the syntax error

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method interrupt() from the type Thread

Also when I make the boolean stop volatile the thread is still running.

Comment: You have two bugs; you need both to use `volatile` and interrupt the blocking thread.

Comment: I've tried both those, and added the error in the original post.

Comment: Search for that error; it's a dupe, but I can't mark it duplicate for a few minutes yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread is blocking on `b.readLine()` as that line of code causes thread execution to halt until there is some input available.

To "force" stop, use `Thread.interrupt()`

E.g:

```
stopChecking.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        //To clarify the following uses a INSTANCE of CheckFiles, called CheckFiles.
        //In other words, somewhere there was a declaration with the format:
        // CheckFiles CheckFiles = ...

        CheckFiles.stop = true;
        CheckFiles.interrupt(); //Or whatever the name of your thread instance is
        System.out.println(CheckFiles.stop); //Prints true when pressed

    }
});
```

The internal reading loop should also be modified as such:

```
while(!stop && (line = b.readLine()) != null){
    Ststem.out.println(line);
}
```

As the interrupt merely unblocks the I/O, we need to check if stop is still `false` before we proceed to do another blocking read.

As others have suggested, an alternative way is to directly invoke `b.close()` after setting `stop = true;`.

**Edit:**

Like Vakh has said, you should also make your boolean `volatile` so that updates to the `stop` variable are immediately visible to all threads.

Comment: I can't interrupt the thread, added the error in the original post.

Comment: @user2612619 Few things you need to look out for. **1.** Don't make your stop variable `static` or else you'll stop all threads when you may only want to stop one. **2.** Perform the `interrupt()` method on your actual thread instance object. By doing `CheckFile.interrupt()` you are accessing the `interrupt()` method statically because you are referring to it directly by class rather than by an instance.

Comment: If I don't make the variable static then I can't access it from the other method where the button is located. Also I am interrupting it like how you did in the example.

Comment: @user2612619 That is my point, you **shouldn't** be attempting to modify the status of **one** thread instance with static methods. My example simply assumes you have an object instance called `CheckFiles` (_See the comment after the statement_)

Comment: So how should I change the status of the thread? And I currently only have one running.

Comment: @user2612619 Can you post the code you used to start the thread with? Somewhere along the line you created a new `CheckFiles` object. Use that instance to call `interrupt()`

Comment: Outside the method I declare 'Thread t = new Thread(new CheckFiles());' and then use 't.start();' to start it. The reason it's outside the method when declaring it is so I can use 't.interrupt();' in the mousePressed method.

Comment: @user2612619 Given that your class extends `Thread`, you'd be better off writing `CheckFiles t = new CheckFiles();` and then `t.start();`. But regardless, call `interrupt()` like you said, with `t.interrupt()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40888/discussion-between-cpu-terminator-and-user2612619)

Answer (score 2):

You must declare `stop` as `volatile`:

```
static volatile boolean stop = false;
```

Basically, `volatile` implies that every thread accessing a `volatile` field will read its current value before continuing, instead of (potentially) using a cached value, which seems to occur in your case where the compiler assumes that the `stop` value is always false in your thread since it never writes an other value for it.

Comment: The thread is still running it even after declaring it as volatile.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop the bufferedreader with b.close(), wouldn't that stop the thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use the threads interruption flag for termination:

```
public class FileChecker implements Callable<Void> {
    private final File location;

    public FileChecker(File location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try (BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                            throw new InterruptedException();
                        }
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // restore interruption flag
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You can now schedule your file checker using an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new FileChecker(...));
```

Stop the file checker by either cancelling the `Future` or shutting down the executor:

```
future.cancel(true);
executor.shutdownNow();
```